# Is it possible to assert manually typed text is present in a text field to validate an 'Undo' button's functionality?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have a table with a form below it.  You can fill out the form, but hitting the 'Undo' button will revert any entered information to what it was before edits were made.

I would like to assert the text that is manually entered so I can confirm the 'Undo' button is reverting the fields.  The 'value' attribute does not change unless the item is saved, so I cannot use that for attribute for assertion.  The XPath for a field is below if that will help.

```
<table id="userAdminForm" class="c4i-ui-fieldGrid">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="c4i-labelCell">
      <td class="c4i-fieldCell" rowspan="1" colspan="1">
        <div class="c4i-fieldDiv rel" style="min-height: 36px">
           <input id="userName" class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" type="text" value="Super User" name="userName" role="textbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-multiline="false">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I needed to grab the "value" attribute from the html to get the text.  The following code works to pass the test when ran and it will fail if the "oldtext" string is not the desired text.

Thanks to Hari for getting me on the right track.

```
WebElement userName = findElementById("userName");
    userName.click();
    userName.clear();
    userName.sendKeys("testforUndo");

    WebElement undo = findElementById("cancel");
    undo.click();

    String text = findElementById("userName").getAttribute("value");
    String oldtext = "Testing";

    Assert.assertTrue(text.equals(oldtext));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first enter some text in the username field by using -

```
driver.findElement(By.id("userName")).sendKeys("some name");
```

then you can click on the **undo** button. If you provide the full source of your html page then I can give you the code to click on the undo button.

Then read the text in the username field by -

```
String text = driver.findElement(By.id("userName")).getText();
```

Then you can verify the value of text and check the functionality of the undo button. If text is empty then it means that the **undo** button is working properly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice!  I needed to use .getAttribute("value") instead of .getText() to return the text written inside of the text box.  Thanks for getting me on the right track!